# website working speed

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, web, web-testing

does anyone know of a decent website analysis tool (preferably freeware).

i searched for it, but most of them report overall webpage loading speed.

my need is to, find percentage of speed consumed by individual components , such as

```
Javascripts/Jquery (http requests etc.)
Images
Objects Flash/Applets/Silverlight
Rendering time of CSS3 stylesheets 
Server Callbacks
```

The website is written in asp.net. it uses masterpages. it has ajax,jquery,flash,css3,html5 objects. it uses Csharp as language.

thanks

Comment: how about the built in developer tools in Chrome?

Comment: ctrl+shift+J in Chrome, tabs Network, Profiles and Timeline are not sufficient? For firefox rely on Firebug, in IE9 F12 might give you some basics. If you already tried that, elaborate on your problem.

Comment: thanks, but is there a a browser independent solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer this one

http://www.webpagetest.org/

because have the option to select the location for the test and the browser.

Also have the option to run more than one test, recognize that the first one is usually slower than the next times, show all the times, screen shots, errors, etc.

Comment: this is indeed a excellent side. Agreed, it has also options for browsers apart from locations. however it is slower in comparison to pingdom

Comment: @arvind Is slow because its have a lot of request. Its very important to see the speed on different location on earth, this is the important  about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

http://tools.pingdom.com

This provides the time taken for connection, wating and recieve time for individual files(html, css, avascript, images, text documents and other files)

Answer (score 0):

you can use YSlow add-on (e.g., https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/yslow/) where you can see load time for images, javascript etc individually.

Also in Firebug browser add-on you can see each content loaded time under Network setting. It is available for free.